# Change object to array and use map function in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dictionary, map-function

I get list response from django server. This is what responseJson.bill looks like

```
[
  {"ch": 0, "day": 9, "de": 0, "dr": 0, "en": 0, "etc": 1600, "id": 111, "ja": 0, "joy": 0, "ko": 0, "location": "경기 부", "month": 6, "mt": 0, "name": "삼계", "price": 1600, "shop": 0, "user_id_id": 2, "year": 2022},
  {"ch": 0, "day": 9, "de": 0, "dr": 0, "en": 0, "etc": 17, "id": 112, "ja": 0, "joy": 0, "ko": 0, "location": "경기 부개", "month": 6, "mt": 0, "name": "chicken", "price": 17, "shop": 0, "user_id_id": 2, "year": 2022}, 
  {"ch": 0, "day": 9, "de": 0, "dr": 0, "en": 0, "etc": 0, "id": 113, "ja": 0, "joy": 0, "ko": 18, "location": "경기 부개", "month": 6, "mt": 0, "name": "galbi", "price": 18, "shop": 0, "user_id_id": 2, "year": 2022}
];
```

In react native, type of "bill" is object now and I want to change to array and use map function to show those lists at screen

I want to etract just "name" and "price" properties from list and show at the screen
What should I do?

I tried to use map function but error says "can't use map function in object"

Here's my code

```
import React, {useState, Component} from 'react';
import {Alert, View, Text, SafeAreaView, TextInput, StyleSheet, Image, Pressable, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
import {Calendar} from 'react-native-calendars'
import {
  LineChart,
  ProgressChart,
  ContributionGraph,
} from "react-native-chart-kit";


 const LedgerScreen = () => {
  const [bill, setBill] = useState(false);
  const [datebill, setDateBill] = useState(false);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const get_today = async() => {
    const now = new Date();
    const year = now.getFullYear();
    const month = now.getMonth() + 1;
    const day = now.getDate();

    const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData');
    const profile = JSON.parse(userData);

    fetch('http://13.209.105.69:8001/user/date/', {
    //fetch('http://localhost:8000/user/date/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: "Token " + profile.token,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        year: year,
        month: month,
        day: day,
      })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
        if(responseJson.status === 'success') {
              setBill(JSON.stringify(responseJson.list));
              //alert(bill);
        } else {
            alert("fail");
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
  }

  const get_calendar_day = async(Date) => {
      const year = Date.year
      const month = Date.month
      const day = Date.day

      const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData');
      const profile = JSON.parse(userData);

      fetch('http://13.209.105.69:8001/user/date/', {
      //fetch('http://localhost:8000/user/date/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: "Token " + profile.token,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          year: year,
          month: month,
          day: day,
        })
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
          console.log(responseJson);
          if(responseJson.status === 'success') {
              setDateBill(JSON.stringify(responseJson.list));
          } else {
              alert("fail");
          }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
      });
  }

  return (
  <View>
    <Modal
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
            setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}
    >
      <View style={styles.modalView}>
        <Calendar
            onDayPress={day => {
                get_calendar_day(day)
            }}
            style={styles.calendar}
            hideExtraDays={true}
        />
        <Pressable
            onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
        >
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>접기</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    </Modal>
    <View style={styles.view}>
      <Pressable
          onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}
      >
          <Image
            source={require('../../Image/calendar.png')}
            style={styles.ImageIconStyle}
          />
      </Pressable>
      <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => get_today()}
      >
        <Text>오늘의 소비</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    <Text>
      {bill}
    </Text>
  </View>
  );
};

export default LedgerScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  calendar: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#e0e0e0',
  },
   modalView: {
      margin: 20,
      backgroundColor: "white",
      borderRadius: 20,
      padding: 35,
      alignItems: "center",
      shadowColor: "#000",
      shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 2
      },
      shadowOpacity: 0.25,
      shadowRadius: 4,
      elevation: 5
   },
   textStyle: {
      color: "black",
      textAlign: "center"
   },
   ImageIconStyle: {
        padding: 10,
        margin: 10,
        height: 25,
        width: 25,
   },
   view: {
     padding: 10,
     margin: 45,
     flexDirection: 'row',
     justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',
   }
});
```

I tried to use map function in here

```
<Text>
      {bill}
</Text>
```

Comment: It's not clear where you're using `map` but it wouldn't work because of this line `setDateBill(JSON.stringify(responseJson.list));` - you're setting your state to a string which doesn't have a `map` method. Just do `setDateBill(responseJson.list);` instead. Or possibly `setDateBill(responseJson);`.

Answer (score 0):

From the data you showed as the response from the server, the type by default is Array (an array of objects) but you are converting it to test using JSON.stringify. Instead of converting that to string, store the response directly as

```
setBill(responseJson.list);
```

It will now store an array in bill (if responseJson.list is an array).

After that, you can directly use map function instead of your `<Text>{bill}</Text>`

```
{bill.map((x, i) => {
    return <Text>{x.name} {x.price}</Text>
})}
```

Again it depends on the data being received from the server. If responseJson.list is array by default, setBill will have an array

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed my code but still getting errors: undefined is not a function (near '...bill.map...') . Is this means that responseJson.list is not an array? If so, How can I check responseJson.list is array?

Comment: What does `console.log(responseJson);` tell you @김소흥

Comment: This is what console.log(responseJson) looks. I omitted inner data and it is same as upper code

Comment: {"list": [ {}, {}, {}] , "status": "success"} @Andy

Comment: Change your initial state for `bill` to an empty array: `const [bill, setBill] = useState([]);` and maybe add an additional line `if (!bill.length) return <div>No data</div>;` before the main return to check that there is data in state.

Comment: @김소흥 responseJson.list is is [{}, {}, {}], so it means the Bill will be equals = [{}, {}, {}]; The data received from backend is not correct as it is sending an array with empty objects.

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert inner objects into an array. You can loop over the main array and then get the inner object properties via using `map`.

Demo **:**

```js
class LoopThrough extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.bills.map(bill => (
          <li key={bill.id}>Name: <b>{bill.name}</b>, Price: <b>{bill.price}</b></li>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <LoopThrough bills={[
  {"ch": 0, "day": 9, "de": 0, "dr": 0, "en": 0, "etc": 1600, "id": 111, "ja": 0, "joy": 0, "ko": 0, "location": "경기 부", "month": 6, "mt": 0, "name": "삼계", "price": 1600, "shop": 0, "user_id_id": 2, "year": 2022},
  {"ch": 0, "day": 9, "de": 0, "dr": 0, "en": 0, "etc": 17, "id": 112, "ja": 0, "joy": 0, "ko": 0, "location": "경기 부개", "month": 6, "mt": 0, "name": "chicken", "price": 17, "shop": 0, "user_id_id": 2, "year": 2022}, 
  {"ch": 0, "day": 9, "de": 0, "dr": 0, "en": 0, "etc": 0, "id": 113, "ja": 0, "joy": 0, "ko": 18, "location": "경기 부개", "month": 6, "mt": 0, "name": "galbi", "price": 18, "shop": 0, "user_id_id": 2, "year": 2022}
]} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.14.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.14.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the element like this rather once the data is fetched

```
setBill(responseJson.list);
```

and then map the variable to the dom like this.

```
    {bill.map((item, index)=>(

    <Text>{bill.name}</Text>
    ))}
```

Lastly, I would add a useEffect with a listener waiting for the bill value like so

```
  useEffect(() => {

   //called functions on page load

  },[bill])
```